# Draggable black circle icon should not drag outside the gray circle(using jquery ui draggable)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I am using jQuery UI Draggable for this. You can check my code in this codepen link. This black circle icon should not move outside gray circle.

```
<div id="groundarea">
    <div class="player player1">
    </div>
    <div class="player player2">
    </div>
</div>
```

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".player").draggable({
        containment: "#groundarea",
        cursor: "grabbing"
    });
    $(".player" ).on( "dragstop", function( event, ui ) {
        var playerId = $(this).data('playerId');
        var leftPercent = ( 100 * parseFloat(ui.position.left / parseFloat($('#groundarea').width())) );
        var topPercent = ( 100 * parseFloat(ui.position.top / parseFloat($('#groundarea').height())) );
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "./update_position.php",
            cache: false,
            data: {'playerId': playerId, 'leftPercent': leftPercent, 'topPercent': topPercent, 'left': ui.position.left, 'top': ui.position.top},
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (result) {
                console.log(result);
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                console.log(xhr);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Here is code URL https://codepen.io/jaimindarji07/pen/MWmKXdp

Comment: I can see already from the codepen link it meets your expectation.`This black circle icon should not move outside gray circle.` What is your question?

Comment: @JohnNyingi Try to drag/move it outside the gray circle then you can see the problem

Comment: include that in the question, it's hard to guess that's the problem

Comment: @JohnNyingi Updated can you help me